# Block request via htaccess if host contains X

Tags: .htaccess

I have many bots that are accessing my site, and since they use mostly amazon web services to spam with the requests, in the logs it looks like that:

```
ec2-47-128-60-90.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
ad2-47-128-60-30.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

So i would like to know if it possible to create a rule that would block that request, if the host contains `compute.amazonaws.com`.

I tried that but it didn't work:

```
Order Deny,Allow
SetEnvIf Remote_Host compute.amazonaws.com keep_out
Deny from env=keep_out
```

Also tried that but it didn't work:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from compute.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: Normally your web server is not configured to do reverse DNS lookups, because they can really slow down the response and then  Remote Host will not be available or only contain IP-addresses. See the [`HostnameLookups` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#hostnamelookups) - But regardless of the `HostnameLookups` setting, Reverse DNS  always be done when you use host/domain names in https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html .

Comment: You're using legacy syntax with `Order Deny, Allow` - see : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#run-time and should be using `Require not host compute.amazonaws.com`

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately because of that reverse DNS, it doesn't seem to block anything even with :  <RequireAll>
Require all granted
Require not host amazonaws.com
</RequireAll>